# integrate.ode sets t0 values outside of my data range

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I would like to solve the ODE dy/dt = -2y + data(t), between t=0..3, for y(t=0)=1.

I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

t = np.linspace(0, 3, 4)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

linear_interpolation = interp1d(t, data)

def func(y, t0):
    print 't0', t0
    return -2*y + linear_interpolation(t0)

soln = odeint(func, 1, t)
```

When I run this code, I get several errors like this:

> ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
>   odepack.error: Error occurred while calling the Python function named
>   func

My interpolation range is between 0.0 and 3.0.
Printing the value of `t0` in func, I realized that `t0` is actually sometimes above my interpolation range: 3.07634612585, 3.0203768998, 3.00638459329, ... It's why `linear_interpolation(t0)` raises the `ValueError` exceptions.

I have a few  questions:

- how does `integrate.ode` makes `t0` vary? Why does it make `t0` exceed the infimum (3.0) of my interpolation range?
- in spite of these errors, `integrate.ode` returns an array which seems to contain correct value. So, should I just catch and ignore these errors? Should I ignore them whatever the differential equation(s), the `t` range and the initial condition(s)?
- if I shouldn't ignore these errors, what is the best way to avoid them? 2 suggestions:

  - in `interp1d`, I could set `bounds_error=False` and `fill_value=data[-1]` since the `t0` outside of my interpolation range seem to be closed to `t[-1]`:

    ```
    linear_interpolation = interp1d(t, data, bounds_error=False, fill_value=data[-1])
    ```

    But first I would like to be sure that with any other `func` and any other `data` the `t0` will always remain closed to `t[-1]`. For example, if `integrate.ode` chooses a `t0` below my interpolation range, the fill_value would be still `data[-1]`, which would not be correct. Maybe to know how `integrate.ode` makes `t0` vary would help me to be sure of that (see my first question).
  - in `func`, I could enclose the `linear_interpolation` call in a try/except block, and, when I catch a `ValueError`, I recall `linear_interpolation` but with `t0` truncated:

    ```
    def func(y, t0):    
        try:
            interpolated_value = linear_interpolation(t0)
        except ValueError:
            interpolated_value = linear_interpolation(int(t0)) # truncate t0
        return -2*y + interpolated_value
    ```

    At least this solution permits linear_interpolation to still raise an exception if `integrate.ode` makes `t0` >= 4.0 or `t0` <= -1.0. I can then be alerted of incoherent behavior. But it is not really readable and the truncation seems to me a little arbitrary by now.

Maybe I'm just over-thinking about these errors. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal for the `odeint` solver to evaluate your function at time values past the last requested time.  Most ODE solvers work this way--they take internal time steps with sizes determined by their error control algorithm, and then use their own interpolation to evaluate the solution at the times requested by the user.  Some solvers (e.g. the CVODE solver in the Sundials library) allow you to specify a hard bound on the time, beyond which the solver is not allowed to evaluate your equations, but `odeint` does not have such an option.

If you don't mind switching from `scipy.integrate.odeint` to `scipy.integrate.ode`, it looks like the `"dopri5"` and `"dop853"` solvers don't evaluate your function at times beyond the requested time.  Two caveats:

- The `ode` solvers use a different convention for the order of the arguments that define the differential equation.  In the `ode` solvers, `t` is the first argument. (Yeah, I know, grumble, grumble...)
- The `"dopri5"` and `"dop853"` solvers are for non-stiff systems.  If your problem is [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation), they should still give correct answers, but they will do a lot more work than a stiff solver would do.

Here's a script that shows how to solve your example.  To emphasize the change in the arguments, I renamed `func` to `rhs`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


t = np.linspace(0, 3, 4)
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
linear_interpolation = interp1d(t, data)

def rhs(t, y):
    """The "right-hand side" of the differential equation."""
    #print 't', t
    return -2*y + linear_interpolation(t)


# Initial condition
y0 = 1

solver = ode(rhs).set_integrator("dop853")
solver.set_initial_value(y0)

k = 0
soln = [y0]
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t[-1]:
    k += 1
    solver.integrate(t[k])
    soln.append(solver.y)

# Convert the list to a numpy array.
soln = np.array(soln)
```

The rest of this answer looks at how you could continue to use `odeint`.

If you are only interested in linear interpolation, you could simply extend your data linearly, using the last two points of the data.  A simple way to extend the `data` array is to append the value `2*data[-1] - data[-2]` to the end of the array, and do the same for the `t` array.  If the last time step in `t` is small, this might not be a sufficiently long extension to avoid the problem, so in the following, I've used a more general extension.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

t = np.linspace(0, 3, 4)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Slope of the last segment.
m = (data[-1] - data[-2]) / (t[-1] - t[-2])
# Amount of time by which to extend the interpolation.
dt = 3.0
# Extended final time.
t_ext = t[-1] + dt
# Extended final data value.
data_ext = data[-1] + m*dt

# Extended arrays.
extended_t = np.append(t, t_ext)
extended_data = np.append(data, data_ext)

linear_interpolation = interp1d(extended_t, extended_data)

def func(y, t0):
    print 't0', t0
    return -2*y + linear_interpolation(t0)

soln = odeint(func, 1, t)
```

If simply using the last two data points to extend the interpolator linearly is too crude, then you'll have to use some other method to extrapolate a little beyond the final `t` value given to `odeint`.

Another alternative is to include the final `t` value as an argument to `func`, and explicitly handle `t` values larger than it in `func`.  Something like this, where `extrapolation` is something you'll have to figure out:

```
def func(y, t0, tmax):
    if t0 > tmax:
        f = -2*y + extrapolation(t0)
    else:
        f = -2*y + linear_interpolation(t0)
    return f

soln = odeint(func, 1, t, args=(t[-1],))
```

Comment: @CamilleC: I updated my answer with some information about using the `ode` class.

Comment: Notice that if you make your own loop of integration (`while solver.successful() and solver.t < t[-1]: ... solver.integrate(t[k])` in this answer, there is a similar snippet at the scipy doc), the solver does not care, which means (1) it may call the function at other points (as described in this answer), (2) it may not call the function even once per iteration. In particular, point (2) means the function should be referentially transparent: you cannot use it to update some ODE parameter. Make that parameter a part of the ODE state array instead. (Found this answer after having that problem).