# How to pass more data into scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, interpolation, ode

I'm using odeint and need to pass in a force that changes with time along with the position and velocity I am integrating for.  The force is a known data array, so it does not need to be solved for but just plugged into the equation.

Here is the code:

```
def dr_dt(y, t):

    RHO = 1225.0          
    C_D = 0.75             
    A = 6.25e-4            
    G = 9.81               
    M_O = 100.0            
    M_P = 10.8             
    M_F = M_O - M_P        
    T = 1.86               

    M_E = (M_O - M_F) / T

    dy0 = y[1]
    dy1 = (f / (M_O - M_E * t)) - ((1.0 * RHO * C_D * A * y[1]**2)  / (2.0 * (M_O - M_E * t))) - G
    return dy0, dy1

t = np.array([0.031, 0.092, 0.139, 0.192, 0.209, 0.231, 0.248, 0.292, 0.370, 0.475, 0.671, 0.702,
          0.723, 0.850, 1.063, 1.211, 1.242, 1.303, 1.468, 1.656, 1.821, 1.834, 1.847, 1.860])
f = np.array([0.946, 4.826, 9.936, 14.090, 11.446, 7.381, 6.151, 5.489, 4.921, 4.448, 4.258, 
          4.542, 4.164, 4.448, 4.353, 4.353, 4.069, 4.258, 4.353, 4.448, 4.448, 2.933, 1.325, 0.000])

r_o = 0.0
v_o = 0.0
y = odeint(dr_dt, [r_o, v_o], t)
```

I know there is the Dfun parameter in odeint, which I believe could help me in this case, but I couldn't find much information on how to use it.  If someone could pass some info along on that, that would be great.  Or any info on how to use interp1d in this case or simply any other ways to get f into the equation.

Thank you

(This is using python 2.7 if that wasn't implied by the title with scipy in it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create an interpolation object from your force data and send that as an argument to `dr_dt`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def dr_dt(y, t, fint):

    RHO = 1225.0          
    C_D = 0.75             
    A = 6.25e-4            
    G = 9.81               
    M_O = 100.0            
    M_P = 10.8             
    M_F = M_O - M_P        
    T = 1.86               

    M_E = (M_O - M_F) / T

    dy0 = y[1]
    dy1 = (fint(t) / (M_O - M_E * t)) - ((1.0 * RHO * C_D * A * y[1]**2)  / (2.0 * (M_O - M_E * t))) - G
    return dy0, dy1

t = np.array([0.031, 0.092, 0.139, 0.192, 0.209, 0.231, 0.248, 0.292, 0.370, 0.475, 0.671, 0.702,
          0.723, 0.850, 1.063, 1.211, 1.242, 1.303, 1.468, 1.656, 1.821, 1.834, 1.847, 1.860])
f = np.array([0.946, 4.826, 9.936, 14.090, 11.446, 7.381, 6.151, 5.489, 4.921, 4.448, 4.258, 
          4.542, 4.164, 4.448, 4.353, 4.353, 4.069, 4.258, 4.353, 4.448, 4.448, 2.933, 1.325, 0.000])

r_o = 0.0
v_o = 0.0

fint = interp1d(t, f)
y = odeint(dr_dt, [r_o, v_o], t[:-1], args=(fint,))
```

(I found I had to omit the last time point because otherwise it was trying to interpolate beyond the bounds of the original data... I don't know if this will matter to you).

EDIT: if this does matter to you, then there are other `ode` functions that will integrate your differential equation without going beyond the last time point in your series, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031966/integrate-ode-sets-t0-values-outside-of-my-data-range).

Comment: Sweet, thank you that helps a lot.  Everything works except I have one problem still.  I just realized that i still receive incorrect values, and realized that my units on f were wrong.  I need to scale them by a factor or 1000 and now  receive the same error that you received when leaving all of the t values in. `A value in x_new is above the interpolation range`. Any suggestions?

Comment: So from what I'm observing, the value for t runs and eventually hits 1.86672 which exceeds the values provided and then raises the error.  Only problem is I can't understand how to prevent this/why it is happening.

Comment: Another update.  Looks as though the f stops on 4448.  So as far as I can see odeint forces t to jump over its limit and in turn, stop f short (unable to interpolate) and raises the error.  Still no fix though.

Comment: SOLVED. Turns out `odeint` often times runs the function past the values requested.  Not totally sure why.  But this is the reason that once `interp1d` is introduced it causes an error.  I'm assuming `interp1d` does not allow the function to run past its values but `odeint` attempts to. Solution was found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031966/integrate-ode-sets-t0-values-outside-of-my-data-range.

Comment: That's great -- I'm glad you got the interpolation to work. I'll edit in a link to this question/answer.